# Does static electricity dissipate if object is sealed in insulator sphere?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, electricity

I rub a piece of glass against some silk. Normally, left in open air, it would lose its acquired charge. What will happen if after rubbing, I immediately seal it inside a sphere made of insulator material (kind of like a "Faraday cage", but not metal)? Will the glass piece stay charged forever? Assume that no air enters/exits the sphere after putting the glass piece inside.

Since the moisture in the air would only neutralize so much charge per unit volume of air, I think the glass should keep the remaining charge pretty much forever. The walls of the sphere can't dissipate it either as they don't conduct. And unless electric breakdown happens, there is no way the charge is neutralizing through the walls?

Comment: That's how EEPROMs and Flash memories work. These devices can store charge for roughly ten years. Even in the best case the charge will eventually be lost because of ionizing radiation (cosmic rays) that can not be shielded effectively unless you are willing to go underground.

Comment: There are no such thing as a perfect insulator. All real world materials conduct electricity. The bigger the area, the faster. You cannot make a perfect vacuum either, and even if you could, at strong enough fields, the vacuum itself would break down. So there are plenty of limits on the science.

Comment: @FlatterMann Woah! Ten years! That's good enough to be called "forever" for me :)

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent You're right but under a specific field strength, the insulator acts as a near perfect insulator. How long can I expect it to last though? Minutes? Hours? Days?

Comment: It depends upon the geometry and initial conditions. It can be much more than centuries, it can be a few seconds. It might feel funny that insulators can discharge stuff within a few seconds, but again, you have to define things properly for us to judge.

Comment: There's a name for that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electret

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Conditions are earth like, like 35°C temperature and sea level pressure, while humidity like the tropics. As for geometry, what is the best way to get a maximum electric field with minimum charge loss?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent COMMENT #2: Also, what if instead of a piece of glass, I have some charged powder? Like that resulting from contact electrification in flour mills? That way we can pack the container, and have even lesser loss of charge (I think).

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent COMMENT #3: Of the four layers of a triboelectric nanogenerator, one is called the charge "trapping" layer (often some metal oxide). I think this term is used elsewhere too but can't remember. What if we put such a layer between our charged object and the insulator "cage's" walls. Will this be a good slow down of the loss of charge?